# remove slurm sacct command double entries: "extern"

Tags: cluster, parallel-processing, slurm

Jobs currently running show two entries, one of them has an `.extern` suffix.  Completed (or failed) jobs also have a third entry: `.batch`.  Is there a way to remove (or not show these) from the `sacct` output?  What are these entries?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude `.batch` and `.extern` by providing the `-X` option:

```
sacct -X
```